# Console System.CommandLine command one liner with options?

Tags: c#, .net, system.commandline

I have a .net console app where I'm trying to make the code more concise.  Currently to setup a command using System.CommandLine I have something like this:

```
using System.CommandLine;

var rootCommand = new RootCommand("CLI");

var theOption = new Option<int?>("--id", "Database ID");

var theCommand = new Command("stuff", "Do Stuff.") { theOption };

ret.SetHandler((id) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Do stuff on id: {id}");
}, theOption);

rootCommand.Add(theCommand);

return rootCommand.Invoke(args);
```

What I'd like to do is make a one liner, but I'm not sure how to do so since I'm using the variable theOption twice.  How could I do this?  Looking for something like:

```
using System.CommandLine;

var rootCommand = new RootCommand("CLI");

//refactor theOption into below statement
var theOption = new Option<int?>("--id", "Database ID");

rootCommand.Add(
   new Command("stuff", "Do Stuff.") { theOption }
).SetHandler((id) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Do stuff on id: {id}");
}, theOption);

return rootCommand.Invoke(args);
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.  My OCD is acting up without the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge of System.CommandLine, wouldn't you be able to achieve this with a simple extension method?

```
public static RootCommand Add(this RootCommand root, Command command)
{
    root.AddCommand(command);

    return root;
}
```

Something like this maybe? and of course whichever other extensibility you want to add, if you wanna make something neat for combining the command and handler, maybe something like this:

```
public static RootCommand Configure(
    this RootCommand root, 
    Action<int?> handlerAction,
    Option<int?> handlerOption, 
    params Command[] commands)
{
    root.SetHandler(handlerAction, handlerOption);

    for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++)
    {
        root.AddCommand(commands[i]);
    }

    return root;
}
```

That should shorten it to:

```
rootCommand.Configure((id) => { Console.WriteLine($"Do stuff on id: {id}"); }, theOption, theCommand, theCommand2);
```

With however many commands you want, you can also reuse the options for all the commands within the extension method or whatnot, the world is your oyster and all that.